# Android wear app in development stage does not appear in watch launcher

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

When I run my developed android wear app via Android studio, it normally installs in my watch and can be later launched via wear launcher. Not sure what could happen, my latest project does not appear as icon in the launcher anymore, despite I can see the app being  launched and fully  functional, but after the  ambient mode, when the app is moved to the background, I cannot relaunch from the  wear. The only way would be to launch it from Android Studio again.  The app icon was deleted from watch and I cannot figure out why!
When I check the list of packages in the phone via ADB, I can see it listed, but it never appears among installed apps in the wear, and it did few days ago.
I have LG  G Watch R with Android 5.1.1,  Android Wear  1.3.0.2166028, and Android Studio 1.5.0/141.2422023

Comment: Have you designated any activity in your manifest as the launcher activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is what I figured out by trying different manifest setups:

When providing the intent filter to start your main activity in the wear manifest as a combination of action.Main and action.TRACK category with mime type /running, the activity will not register in the launcher with an icon, only voice action OK GOOGLE START RUNNING will launch the activity. 

<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="vnd.google.fitness.TRACK"/>
                <data   android:mimeType="vnd.google.fitness.activity/running"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</intent-filter>


To get the icon back to the  launcher I had to make a compromise of loosing the ability to start the main activity with the voice launcher. 

<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter>
```